# Contact lenses come in two polymer classes, ionic or non-ionic. Whats the significance of having both?

Tags: polymers

As a contact lenses user, I was looking for information about why manufacturers produce soft contacts using polymers from both classes. Common knowledge would suggest that something placed in contact over the eyes for corrective vision should be inert. Ionic usually means more reactive. So why do they even make ionic contacts?

Comment: I have no knowledge on this topic, but am a fellow contact lens user. What brands offer ionic vs. non-ionic lenses?

Comment: I just edited my question taking your comment in consideration .

Comment: I don't know, if you had some specific question about the properties of these polymers or something, you might get some good answers, but I'm not sure the question of what is "better" for contact lenses is on topic here.

Comment: 'Better' means 'more healthy'. I would like to be an informed buyer. This information is not available for the consumer. I just edited my question taking your comment in consideration .

Comment: Um, unfortunately, now your edit renders this question off-topic. We can't safely answer questions related to health. That's what doctors are for.